# Using @Qualifier and @Bean together in Java Config Spring

Tags: spring

I have follow code

```
interface Drivable {

}

@Component
class Bmw implements Drivable {

}

@Component
class Mercedes implements Drivable {

}

class Driver {
    private Drivable drivable;

    public Driver(Drivable drivable) {
        this.drivable = drivable;
    }
}
```

And Spring Java Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class CarConfig {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mercedes")//the code won't work
    public Driver getDriver(Drivable drivable) {
        return new Driver(drivable);
    }

    @Bean//I've added the bean
    public Drivable getMercedes() {
        return new Mercedes();
    }
}
```

Can I use `@Qualifier` annotation with `@Bean` annotation if I want to specify type of object that should pass to method?  I can't find in Spring doc how I can solve the problem. Thx.

Comment: If you want to limit the parameter to a specific type, just make it take that specific type. `getDriver(Mercedes mercedes)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you got the usage of `@Qualifier` bit wrong.

If we have more than one bean that qualifies for spring injection, then we use `@Qualifer` to specify which needs to be used for injection.

In this case you have two beans `Bmw` and `Mercedes` both implementing `Drivable` interface.

Presuming I got your intent correct, you want spring to inject `Mercedes` bean into the `Driver` object.

So for that, you need to specify `public Driver getDriver(@Qualifier("mercedes") Drivable drivable)` in the `CarConfig` class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class CarConfig {
    @Bean
    public Driver getDriver(@Qualifier("mercedes") Drivable drivable) {
        return new Driver(drivable);
    }
```

And then you can use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to load the spring context and subsequently get the `Driver` bean as below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CarConfig.class);
        Driver bean = ctx.getBean(Driver.class);
    }
}
```

Just to extend the example, let us say if you want to create a `Driver` bean for each of `Bmw` and `Mercedes` then the sample code would be:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class CarConfig {
    @Bean(name="mercedesDriver")
    public Driver getMercedesDriver(@Qualifier("mercedes") Drivable drivable) {
        return new Driver(drivable);
    }

    @Bean(name="bmwDriver")
    public Driver getBmwDriver(@Qualifier("bmw") Drivable drivable) {
        return new Driver(drivable);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CarConfig.class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ctx.getBeanNamesForType(Driver.class)));
        Driver mercedesBean = ctx.getBean("mercedesDriver", Driver.class);
        Driver bmwBean = ctx.getBean("bmwDriver", Driver.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, it works, but if I add to config class method that return object of Mercedes I'll have `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`. I've edit my code.

Comment: I think that is because you still have `@Bean  @Qualifier("mercedes") public Driver getDriver(Drivable drivable) {return new Driver(drivable); }`. You need to replace that with `@Bean(name="mercedesDriver") public Driver getMercedesDriver(@Qualifier("mercedes") Drivable drivable) {return new Driver(drivable); }`. And by the way, you won't need the `method that return object of Mercedes`. You have already marked you `Mercedes` class and `@Component` and so spring already recognises that as a bean.

Comment: In Spring 5.2 @Qualifier cannot be applied to a method parameter (i.e. @Qualifier("bmw") Drivable in your example). I don't know whether it's a recent change.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class CarConfig {

@Bean
public Driver mercedesDriver(Drivable bmw) {
    return new Driver(bmw);
}

// same as
@Bean("mercedesDriver")
public Driver getDriver(Drivable bmw) {
    return new Driver(bmw);
}
```

.....

```
@Autowired private Driver mercedesDriver;
```

In Spring you an relate on dependency injection by name. In the first example the name is defined by the method name. In the second example the method name is not important, because wie name the bean through the Annotation. Its very easy and simple. Not really need for `@Qualifier`. Only if the name should be different, but why?

Answer (score 1):

You could define qualifiers for each specific implementations of interface Drivable. Once you did, now you could autowire them into CarConfig class and you have to be create Beans for each Drivers(Mercedz & Benz) along with qualifier names.

Find below Implementation:

```
 @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Qualifier
 public @interface Bmw {
 }

 @Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Qualifier
 public @interface Mercedes {
 }
```

Now your Interface Implementations of Driver should be annotated with Qualifiers as below

```
@Compoenent
@Bmw
public interface Bmw implements Drivable{
}

@Component
@Mercedes
public interface Mercedes implements Drivable{
}
```

Your CarConfig class should be as below:

```
@Configuration
public class CarConfig{

@autowire
@Bmw
private Drivable bmwDriver;

@autowire
@Mercedes
private Drivable mercedesDriver;


@Bean
public Bean getBmwDriver(){
  return new Bmw(bmwDriver);
  }

 @Bean
public Bean getMercedesDriver(){
   return new Mercedes(mercedesDriver);
  }

 }
```

NOTE: if you are creating bean with @Bean, it will be injected byType if there is duplicates then it will injected byName. we no need to mention @Bean(name="bmwDriver") .
so you can directly use qualifier("bmwDriver") wherever you need in classes.

Comment: Nice, this is a missing part in the Spring documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired-qualifiers.html. The documentation contains the XML example for qualifying by type, but doesn't mention that custom qualifier may be applied to the bean definition.

The only one note: the definition of custom qualifier must include `ElementType.TYPE` in the target.

Answer (score -1):

You can still you @Primary in Mercedes component, which will automatically take Mercedes as primary component while dependency injection. For other beans you could use qualifier in dependency injection.