# How to add @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, configuration

How can I add a qualifier to distinguish between these two beans? I know I need to use the @Qualifier annotation but I am not sure how to add it in the beans and then how to create the autowired object with reference to the appropriate bean.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@PropertySources(PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
                 PropertySource(value = ["file:\${credentials.config}"]))
class CredentialsConfig(@Autowired private val env: Environment) {

    @Bean fun getCredentials(): Credentials? {
        val user: String = env.getRequiredProperty("user1")
        val pass: String = env.getRequiredProperty("pass1")
        return Credentials.info(user, pass)
    }

    @Bean fun getCredentials2(): Credentials {
        val user: String = env.getRequiredProperty("user2")
        val pass: String = env.getRequiredProperty("pass2")
        return Credentials.info(user, pass)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

Comment: @see [using-qualifier-and-bean-together-in-java-config-spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127000/using-qualifier-and-bean-together-in-java-config-spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, I find it beneficial to explicitly name my beans so it is more clear which one I am picking. Otherwise, you will end up with what Spring decides to call it (based on the method name). When we want to inject a bean, but there are more than one of them, we use the `@Qualifer` annotation *at the injection point*, specifying the name of the bean we care about.

So...

```
// In CredentialsConfig

@Bean("firstCredentials) fun firstCredentials(): Credentials = TODO()
@Bean("secondCredentials) fun secondCredentials(): Credentials = TODO()
```

And when wiring in one of these, you can add a `@Qualifier` to pick your specific implementation (note, if you use constructor injection, you don't need `@Autowired`):

```
@Component
class MyComponent(@Qualifier("firstCredentials") creds: Credentials) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add @Qualifier with bean name whenever you do an Autowire of Credentials.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("getCredentials")
Credentials credentials;
```

Comment: And what should I add above the bean declarations? @Quallifier as well?

Comment: You could name your beans like @Bean("credentials1") and @Bean("credentials2")

Comment: By default, it will be the method name, so its up to you to. I find it better to give better name to the beans