# Autowired/Dependencies injection doesn't work in a Spring Shell project

Tags: java, spring, spring-shell

I started a new project from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-shell-cli

I was trying to use dependency injection or `Autowired` annotation on my `BannerProvider` class. But Spring raise an exception.

**My Application class**
After many customization

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCLIApplication extends Bootstrap {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(MyCLIApplication.class, args));
    }
}
```

**My BannerProvider Component**

```java
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyBannerProvider extends DefaultBannerProvider {

    private final Point screenSize;

    public MyBannerProvider(@Qualifier("ScreenSize") Point screenSize) {
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
    }

    [other stuff]
}
```

**My POM dependencies**

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jline</groupId>
            <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
            <version>${jline.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Run error**

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("ScreenSize")

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - User-defined bean method 'screenSize' in 'TerminalConfiguration'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'my.namespace.Point' in your configuration.
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: Does Point bean has ScreenSize name in Configuration class? Smth like 
 @Bean("ScreenSize ") ?

Comment: Yes, it has

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("ScreenSize")
    public Point screenSize() {...}
```

Comment: So Qualifier used when you have more than one implementation of interface and when you need to select one of them. Text in Qualifier is exact bean name. I think you need to delete Qualifier from your @Bean configuration and from your MyBannerProvider too, and i think it should work. Also here is good explanation of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/49155590/1063509

Comment: Do not works:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in my.namespace.MyBannerProvider required a bean of type 'my.namespace.Point' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
 - User-defined bean method 'screenSize' in 'TerminalConfiguration'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'my.namespace.Point' in your configuration.
```

Comment: is it difficult to understand what goes wrong without code, is it possible to upload project somewhere on github for example?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the mystery by myself.

The key was on the Online tutorial. It suggest to write a setup file `META-INF/spring/spring-shell-plugin.xml`.

This file is something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.namespace.too.specific.path"/>
</beans>
```

But it has effect on **all** Spring behaviours, so you need to configure all your beans into `my.namespace.too.specific.path`. Or nothing works.

Maybe is a newbie error. But I hate `META-INF` setup files, and I try to avoid them in all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in you bean creation:
`@Bean  @Qualifier("ScreenSize")  public Point screenSize() {...}`

1. @Qualifier annotation is not used to create a bean, it's used with @autowired  to eliminate the issue of which bean needs to be injected when you have several beans with same type .
2. If you need to specify the name(id) of bean you should use in this case: `@Bean("ScreenSize")`
   *Note that if you didn't specify the name of the bean inside @Bean annotation, by default the name concidered by the container is the same as the name of method, in your case it's "screenSize".

below the solution to your question:

1. To declare your Point bean:
   `@Bean(name="ScreenSize")   public Point screenSize() {...}`
2. To inject the bean:
   `@Autowired public MyBannerProvider(@Qualifier("ScreenSize") Point screenSize) { this.screenSize = screenSize; }`